# .htaccess rewrite for keeping a trailing variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` rewrite attempt is not working. I'd like the request `/directory-1/productorder?i=38371` to go to `/directory-2/38371` where the number `38371` can vary.

My rewrite so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/directory1/productorder?i=(.+)$ /directory2/$1 [L]
```

The page is not redirecting with my current implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/?directory-1/productorder\?i=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory2/%1? [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Your rewriterule is not working because of the following reasons :

1) A leading slash in RewriteRule directive is not required if you are using apache version 2.

2) Query string is not a part of match in RewriteRule.

Comment: Thank you @Starkeen. The page is not redirecting with your implementation.

Comment: Try the updated answer ,I have added a NE no-escape flag to the rewrite rule

Comment: Thank you @Starkeen. Yeah, I had the same thought and had escaped the ? but didn't add the NE no-escape flag. The result was no redirection at all. So I thought I was not on the right track. Escaping the ? and adding the NE no-escape flag did the trick.